# Use mbtiles to add custom data provider as layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

We have a custom server that serves raster in a bounding box. So parameters are selected raster id's, bounding box and so on in a payload.

Our user wants a plugin to use it. They also want more detail as they zoom in.

I could not manipulate classes such as QgsDataProviders to my advantage. With limited options I continued with mbtiles.

I have test of a mbtiles with following steps:

- added mbtiles as a qgis layer
- added a tile on a zoom level that **already have tiles surrounding it at the same zoom level**
- called layer.reload()

That worked.

I wrote a custom layer that:

- creates an empty mbtiles
- finds tiles in the canvas
- request them and place it in the mbtiles
- when a new tile is inserted, triggered layer.reload() with time periods.

I get errors because by the time I have add the layer the mbtiles was empty (min, max zoom error).
So I inserted some fake data in the initialization. Still did not work.

In the second test I manually add a tile on an empty zoom level while the layer was active, called layer.reload(), the layer have broken.
I added the same mbtiles on a second layer. It only showed the tile that inserted on 1 level above.
Then I deleted the tile that 1 level above, called layer.reload() on both. The first layer come back to its previous state. The second layer lost the only tile and displayed nothing.

In my opinion, the optimization abstraction are coming into my way.

I have stack on this problem. Any idea to make it work?

Comment: why not base it on a WMS layer?

Comment: The user selects which raster files they want to see, They all written in a post. The management want to use the service we already have and it is not appropriate for the use case. 

I will insist on a new (tile, wms) service.

Comment: but a plugin based on a WMS layer seems more suited to this issue than trying to make mbtiles work

Comment: I changed create a new end-point for xyz tiles. That works. Thanks @IanTurton

Answer (score 0):

I have created an xyz tile server does the same job. Now I can add the layer.

```py
url = "type=xyz&url=" + self.url +"/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D" + args_as_string
layer = QgsRasterLayer(self.url, layer_name, "wms")
if layer.isValid():
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
else:
    print("Layer failed to load!")
```